# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘getValues’ for signature

Tags: raster, r

I was trying to convert the raster to vector/matrix using **getValues** and I am getting this error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘getValues’ for signature ‘"character", "missing", "missing"
```

I have put the code below for reference.

```
#mosaic

Mosaic<- "Mosaic.tif"

#shapefile

shp <- "Tahsil Boundary2001.shp"

#Extacted Raster

gondia<- "extract.tif"

#convert raster to vector\matrix

nr <- getValues(gondia)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you want to use `getValues` from `raster` package. You have to create raster object with `raster()` function. In your case you just store string `"extract.tif"` into variable `gondia` so:

```
gondia <- "extract.tif"
gondia
```

results in

```
[1] "extract.tif"
```

Just try:

```
gondia <- raster("extract.tif")
nr <- getValues(gondia)
```

For further details see `getValues` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.4-5/topics/getValues).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried as you suggested and it worked. I will go through for more information.

Comment: Perfect, please if the answer solved your question, mark it as "accepted", which indicates that this thread is resolved. Also see quick starting tour at  https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour